# Swiftyjson - JSON to table view with alphabetical sections

Tags: json, swift, tableview, swifty-json

Once I get the JSON back from my http request through Alamofire, I get the following swiftyjson JSON object mentioned at the bottom of this post.

How can I extract the sections in this format?

- var sections : [(index: Int, length :Int, title: String)] = Array()
- length being the number of contact under each section. Title the letter

And then how can I extract each array of object under each letter?

All of that using swift.

The objective is to create a list of contacts with a tableview and alphabetical sections.

Please let me know if I'm not clear.

JSON object:

```
{
  "T" : [
    {
      "location" : "Shanghai",
      "firstName" : "User3",
      "id" : 3,
      "created_at" : "2016-04-19 12:54:23",
      "birthDate" : "2016-04-17",
      "email" : "user3@test.com",
      "profilePhotoPath" : "photos\/emptyProfilePhoto.jpg",
      "updated_at" : "2016-04-19 12:54:23",
      "lastName" : "Test"
    }
  ],
  "G" : [
    {
      "location" : "Jakaylaborough",
      "firstName" : "Lambert",
      "id" : 4,
      "created_at" : "2016-04-19 23:25:39",
      "birthDate" : "0000-00-00",
      "email" : "user4@test.com",
      "profilePhotoPath" : "photos\/emptyProfilePhoto.jpg",
      "updated_at" : "2016-04-19 23:25:39",
      "lastName" : "Gulgowski"
    }
  ],
  "W" : [
    {
      "location" : "East Sydni",
      "firstName" : "Jedediah",
      "id" : 5,
      "created_at" : "2016-04-19 23:25:39",
      "birthDate" : "0000-00-00",
      "email" : "user5@test.com",
      "profilePhotoPath" : "photos\/emptyProfilePhoto.jpg",
      "updated_at" : "2016-04-19 23:25:39",
      "lastName" : "Wehner"
    },
    {
      "location" : "East Rebeccaton",
      "firstName" : "Addison",
      "id" : 6,
      "created_at" : "2016-04-19 23:25:39",
      "birthDate" : "0000-00-00",
      "email" : "user6@test.com",
      "profilePhotoPath" : "photos\/emptyProfilePhoto.jpg",
      "updated_at" : "2016-04-19 23:25:39",
      "lastName" : "Weimann"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like a relatively painless process using reduce.

Comment: @JefferyThomas the code in my answer below is working. The only issue is that my sections are not in alphabetical order...

Comment: @JefferyThomas Last issue solved and answer edited below. Let me know if any comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my way. Answer below.

```
var sections : [(index: Int, length :Int, title: String)] = Array()
var contactsSorted: [JSON] = [JSON]()

// Delegate from my contact protocol
func didReceiveContacts(contacts: JSON){

    var index = 0

    for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in contacts {

        let title = "\(key)"

        let newSection = (index: index, length: subJson.count, title: title)

        sections.append(newSection)

        contactsSorted.append(subJson)

        index += 1
    }
    // EDIT:Sort the sections by title to retrieve the alphabetical order
    sections.sortInPlace({ $0.title < $1.title })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

// tableView delegate methods

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return sections.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return sections[section].title

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return sections[section].length

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactCell")! as! ContactTableViewCell

cell.nameLabel.text = contactsSorted[sections[indexPath.section].index].array![indexPath.row]["firstName"].string! + " " + contactsSorted[sections[indexPath.section].index].array![indexPath.row]["lastName"].string!

}
```